# How to change text color on menu item

Tags: java, swt, menuitem, system-tray

I'm using Java and SWT. I have added menu(on right click) to system tray. I want to change color of the text on menu items. Is it possible? I couldn't find any solution about this.

```
 TrayItem item = new TrayItem(tray, SWT.NONE);
 item.addListener(SWT.MenuDetect, new Listener() {
      public void handleEvent(org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Event event) {
           Menu menu = new Menu(shell, SWT.POP_UP);
           MenuItem item1 = new MenuItem(menu, SWT.NONE);
           item1.setText("Settings");   // **i want to change color of the text**
      }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not possible yet. There is a bug report [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=168716).

Comment: but there is no setForeground method for menuitem.

Answer (score -1):

```
item1.setForeground(Color.red);
```

u mean this one??